# qemu (no virt-manager/viewer) sdl window fullscreen with high resolution

Tags: x11, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

I'm trying to open a KVM VM fullscreen without a user being able to close the window of Qemu SDL GUI. My test machine has 1680x1050 resolution, but I'm NOT able to make any VM GUI to be fullscreen as my 1680x1050 resolution.

BTW, I'm opening it directly, not via SPICE. Let's imagine a scenario when this VM would be started and made fullscreen on a user monitor when his computer boots (ie. instead of X11 WM there would be directly started qemu SDL GUI).

Any idea how to achieve same resolution in qemu SDL window as the virtual host machine has? IIUC `-vga std` should cover such revolution.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-vga std \
-accel kvm \
-smp 2 -m 2048 \
-boot c -cdrom <livecd> -bios bios-256k.bin -boot menu=on \
-hda <disk> \
-display sdl,alt_grab=on,window_close=off \
-usb -device usb-tablet \
-full-screen
```

Comment: IIUC `-vga virtio` needs driver in guest, am i right?

Comment: IIUC there must be a driver for guest OS, there's one for Linux but missing for Windows.

Comment: Not a solution but... `-display spice-app` calls XDG-based app for spice url scheme (see `xdg-settings get default-url-scheme-handler spice`), thus one could create a wrapper with `remote-viewer -f -k --kiosk-quit=never <socket>`. But I would prefer native solution... With spice fullscreen resolution is OK.

Comment: Wrapper: `desktop-file-install --dir ~/.local/share/applications/ /usr/share/applications/remote-viewer.desktop`, `desktop-file-edit --set-key=Exec --set-value='myremote-viewer %u' ~/.local/share/applications/remote-viewer.desktop`, and inside wrapper I do `exec /usr/bin/remote-viewer --kiosk --kiosk-quit=never --full-screen "$@"`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested only with Ubuntu Linux 20.10 (X11) guest VM.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -nodefaults -name test -accel kvm \
-smp 2 -m 2048 -bios bios-256k.bin -boot menu=on \
-cdrom ubuntu-20.10-desktop-amd64.iso \
-device qemu-xhci,id=usb-bus -device usb-tablet \
-display sdl \
...graphics...
-netdev user,id=hostnet0 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0 \
-full-screen -no-quit
```

VGA driver, no defined resolution (bochs_drm kernel, fb X11)

```
-device VGA,vgamem_mb=64 # bad 1024x768
```

VGA driver, defined resolution (bochs_drm kernel, fb X11)

```
-device VGA,vgamem_mb=64,xres=1680,yres=1050 # ok
```

QXL-VGA, qxl driver in guest VM, no defined resolution (qxl kernel, qxl_dri X11)

```
-device qxl-vga,vgamem_mb=64 # bad 1024x768
```

QXL-VGA, qxl driver in guest VM, defined resolution

```
-device qxl-vga,vgamem_mb=64,xres=1680,yres=1050 # ok
```

virtio-vga, driver in guest VM, no defined resolution (virtio-pci kernel, fb/modesettings X11 - not sure here)

```
-device virtio-vga # bad 1024x768
```

virtio-vga, driver in guest VM

```
-device virtio-vga,xres=1680,yres=1050 # ok
```