# How to implement automatic, conditional startup of flatpak applications at login?

Tags: bash, shell-script, autostart, flatpak

Rather than put some applications in `$HOME/.config/autostart` and start them at every login, I want to use a `CASE` statement to define which get launched on which days (some things only get launched on work days, others only on days I have certain meetings, etc. - point is, I want all the chat and messaging things to autostart when I should be reachable and not when it's the weekend), so I write something like this:

```
DAYOFWEEK=$(date +"%u")

case $DAYOFWEEK in
   (1|3|4) flatpak run com.discordapp.Discord && flatpak run com.slack.Slack;;
   (2) flatpak run com.discordapp.Discord && flatpak run com.slack.Slack && flatpak run us.zoom.Zoom;;
   (5) flatpak run com.discordapp.Discord;;
   (6) echo nothing;;
   (7) flatpak run com.slack.Slack;;
   (*) echo day error;;
esac

# always start
flatpak run im.riot.Riot
flatpak run org.signal.Signal
```

Two issues:

1. I don't want to put this in `.bashrc` and have the command sent to start the applications every time I open a new terminal, so where best to put it? `.bash_profile`?
2. The applications in question are all installed as flatpaks. When I put the routine in `.bash_profile`, the first application started on login, but blocked anything else from starting and I had to kill all the applications from my script as they launched, one at a time, before my desktop would load. Trying to insert `&` into the command as when launching from the command line to background an application results here in a syntax error.
   Is getting the applications to start nicely and not interfere with the "regular" login to my desktop affected by them being flatpaks? Regardless, how should I launch them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `~/.config/autostart` and influence it with your wrapper. See [qemu (no virt-manager/viewer) sdl window fullscreen with high resolution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638553/qemu-no-virt-manager-viewer-sdl-window-fullscreen-with-high-resolution#comment1196539_638553)

That means, write a wrapper, put it into `~/bin`, change `.desktop` file to call your wrapper instead of original *Exec* key. The wrapper would have logic you want...